# calculating size of numbers in array in php

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
$broj=array(20,21,10,50,21,9,8,19);
$a=0;
foreach($broj <= 20){
$a + 1;
return $a;}
?>
```

Php says that something is wrong with foreach loop!
how can i see how many numbers in var"$broj" are smaller than 20??

Comment: You cannot use `return` in a loop.

Comment: Uh, yes, something is wrong with the foreach loop.

First, it should be foreach($broj as $something)

Second, the instant it hits the return, it's going to break out of the loop.

Comment: Meanwhile change `$a + 1` to `$a++; ` or `$a += 1`.

Comment: thats not how I rmb foreach is used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$broj=array(20,21,10,50,21,9,8,19);
$a=0;
foreach($broj as $value){
  if($value<=20){
   $a++;
  }
}
echo $a;
?>
```

Comment: You might want to throw some text with your code, explaining what you changed and *why* it was changed.

Comment: it is easy to understand..in fact he approved the answer!

Comment: Even so, any decent answer should have an explanation. Just because it was accepted, doesn't mean it was a good answer. OP clearly didn't know how a `foreach`-loop works, so an explanation of *why* this works would not only help him, but future readers.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo count(array_filter($broj, function($v) {return $v<20;}));
```

Nothing more :)

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/512629)**

Result for your input: **4**

Oh yeah some explanation!

`array_filter` takes your array and applies a `callback` to it and returns the resulting array. In that `callback` method i'm telling it to return only the values that are smaller than 20.

Answer (score 0):

The way a foreach loop works, you have to do the following

```
$testArray = array(1,1,2,3,5,8,13);

foreach($testArray as $number)
{
    .... whatever your loop code is ....
}

.... after foreach code ....
```